# Sandboxing an install

Tags: windows, installation, administrator

I have an install file that goes into building an portable application.  There are a couple of problems with it.  On Vista when I build the portable version the install requests admin privileges even though I'm installing to a regular folder not a program of protected folder.  I also turn off the writing to registry settings.  I'm not sure if the admin permission request stems from the fact that the file has setup in the name (which in vista forces admin privileges).  But my question is is there a way to sandbox the install and make the installer think it has admin privileges but the system is not affected, and perhaps the attempted changes are logged to investigate?

Answer (score 1):

Care telling us which program you're talking about?

As for virtualizing program installations, have a look at **[VMware ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/)**.

Comment: Is there a solution that works for less than $6,000?

Comment: The primary one is R from the R-project.